# Calculate limit of Lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to calculate this limit: $$\lim_n \int_0^{n^2}e^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})dx$$

Since $$\int_0^{n^2}e^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})dx=\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})\mathcal X_{[0,n^2]}dx,$$
then the limit of the problem is equal to $$\lim_n\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})\mathcal X_{[0,n^2]}dx$$

If I'm not mistaken, for each $x$, $\lim_n e^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})\mathcal X_{[0,n^2]}=0$, so, if $f_n=e^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})\mathcal X_{[0,n^2]}$ and I could find an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n| \leq g$, then I could apply the dominated convergence theorem to say $$\lim_n \int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})\mathcal X_{[0,n^2]}dx=\int_{[0,\infty)} \lim_ne^{-x^2}\sin(\frac{x}{n})\mathcal X_{[0,n^2]}dx=0$$

I couldn't do this, any suggestions to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: $\lvert\sin y\rvert \leqslant 1$. Would using that help you see a dominating function?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, yes, I thought of $g=e^{-x^2}$, but I don't have the tools to calculate the integral of $e^{-x^2}$. I know that $\int_{1^{\infty}} e^{-x^2}dx<\int_{1^{\infty} }e^{-x}dx<\dfrac{1}{e}$, I don't know what to do in order to prove $\int_{0^1} e^{-x^2}dx <\infty$.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the integral. To see that it is finite, you can use $1 + x^2 \leqslant e^{x^2}$, whence $e^{-x^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, or you can use $e^{-x^2} \leqslant 1$ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, and $e^{-x^2} \leqslant e^{-x}$ for $x \geqslant 1$, or many other methods.

Comment: See [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These integrands are all dominated by the $\mathcal{L}^1$ function $x\mapsto e^{-x^2}$.  Since they converge pointwise to zero, the integrals go there too.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it trivial?

$$\left|\int_{0}^{n^2}e^{-x^2}\sin\frac{x}{n}\,dx\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n^2}x e^{-x^2}\,dx\leq \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x e^{-x^2}=\frac{1}{2n}. $$